# Реализация onTouchListener требует переопределения performClick в данном View

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Устанавливаю `onTouchListener` на некоторые `View` и `Android Studio` выделяет данные участки кода с формулировкой во всплывающей подсказке:

> "If a View that overrides `onTouchEvent` or uses an `OnTouchListener` does
>   not also implement `performClick` and call it when clicks are detected,
>   the `View` may not handle accessibility actions properly. Logic handling
>   the click actions should ideally be placed in `View#performClick` as
>   some accessibility services invoke performClick when a click action
>   should occur."

Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Помогло решить вопрос следующим образом:

1. Создать класс расширяющий (`extend`) нужный `View`, например `TextView`

   ```
   class MyTextView extends TextView {

       @Override
       public boolean performClick() {
           // если что-то необходимо
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Заменить в `xml` и в коде `TextView` на `MyTextView`